# Replacing Values in a R Dataframe if another Dataframe value is Less than 0

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes in r with the same size.
What I want to do, is remove the value of the first dataframe, if the 2nd dataframe has a value less than zero

for example, if killer_stock dataframe has values less than 0, 
values in rank_stock would be replaced with NA

```
stock <-c('1','2','3')
stock2 <-c('1','2','3')

rank_stock <- data.frame(stock,stock2)

stockc <-c('-1','2','3')
stock2c <-c('2','-1','1')

killer_stock <- data.frame(stockc,stock2c)
```

the result dataframe would look something like below.
but I have a very big dataframe and would also like to rm the value not replace it with chr "NA"

```
stock_r <-c('NA','2','3')
stock_r2 <-c('1','NA','3')

result_stock <- data.frame(stock_r,stock_r2)
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by putting quotes around the values in the vectors, the dataframes end up being columns of factors rather than numeric (if using the default `stringsAsFactors` system option). The first 2 lines of the code I enter below fixes that, but you could skip those if you enter the data differently.

I'll make use of the `dplyr` function `mutate_all`, but there are solutions with the base R family of `apply` functions which you might want to start with if you're new to R. There are many ways to implement a solution, but I am converting the `killer_stock` dataframe to 1 and `NA` if the value is above zero or below, respectively. Then I'm multiplying that dataframe element-wise with the `rank_stock` dataframe. `NA` times any number is any, so those values will get converted.

```
library(dplyr)
# Convert to numeric
killer_stock <- killer_stock %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)
rank_stock <- rank_stock %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)

# Convert to 1 or NA
df <- killer_stock %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(. < 0, NA, 1)))

# Element-wise multiplication
rank_stock * df

  stock stock2
1    NA      1
2     2     NA
3     3      3
```

Comment: but would there be a way to change the killer_stock dataframe to 1 and NA with BASE R function?

Comment: i would like to stay away from dplyr for now because it would mess with my other codes

Comment: `sapply(killer_stock, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, NA, 1))` will generate a matrix of values and multiply the `rank_stock` dataframe in the same way. Why do you think it will mess with the rest of your code? Are you also using `plyr` package?

Comment: i just did x[x<0] <- NA

Comment: Yeah `rank_stock[killer_stock<0] <- NA ` would also work

Comment: woah this last one really will be helpful!! thanks alot!!